# Questions about virtual machines with physical GPUs on MacOS

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

I want to use graphics passthrough on macOS, what should I do? Can it be achieved?

Comment: With some hypervisors and more than one graphics cards yes, it can be done. Which OS is the host?

Comment: host is macos, I am using macbook